# How to group by values from different columns into one row?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a source table that look like this:

[image]

How to make result table looks like this. I could use solution in sql or in java code.

[image]

Please, could anyone help me.
Thanks.

Comment: What makes you put BCDE0010 in the first row vs the second?

Comment: Which database -- SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: The operation you are attempting is called a Pivot.  Try a google search on "pivot table"

Comment: Database is SQL Server, it could be any number of value in the columns. I just need to combine them by account.

Answer (score 10):

I think the easiest way to do this is by applying both the `UNPIVOT` and the `PIVOT` function to get the result:

```
select account, description,
  [value_1], [value_2], [value_3], [value_4]
from
(
  select account, description, col, value,
    row_number() over(partition by account, col order by col) rn
  from 
  (
    select [account], [description], [value_1], [value_2], [value_3], [value_4]
    from yourtable
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value 
    for col in ([value_1], [value_2], [value_3], [value_4])
  ) un
) s
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in ([value_1], [value_2], [value_3], [value_4])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/592c9/7).

This can also be done using a `UNION ALL` as the *unpivot* and an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression:

```
select account, description,
  max(case when col = 'value_1' then value end) value_1,
  max(case when col = 'value_2' then value end) value_2,
  max(case when col = 'value_3' then value end) value_3,
  max(case when col = 'value_4' then value end) value_4
from
(
  select account, description, col, value,
    row_number() over(partition by account, col order by account) rn
  from
  (
    select [account], [description], 'value_1' col, [value_1] value 
    from yourtable
    where [value_1] is not null
    union all
    select [account], [description], 'value_2' col, [value_2] value 
    from yourtable
    where [value_2] is not null
    union all
    select [account], [description], 'value_3' col, [value_3] value 
    from yourtable
    where [value_3] is not null
    union all
    select [account], [description], 'value_4' col, [value_4] value 
    from yourtable
    where [value_4] is not null
  ) s
) un
group by account, description, rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/592c9/13)

Both give the result:

```
| ACCOUNT |  DESCRIPTION |  VALUE_1 |  VALUE_2 |  VALUE_3 |  VALUE_4 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  A00005 | Account Desc | ABCD0081 | BCDE0010 | BKCP0010 | SMTP0010 |
|  A00005 | Account Desc | ABCD0082 |   (null) | BKCP0011 |   (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to use the `Row_Number()` as your joining field.  Something like this:

```
SELECT T.Account, T.Description, T1.Value_1, T2.Value_2, T3.Value_3, T4.Value_4
From 
  (
      SELECT Account, Description, Value_1, Value_2, Value_3, Value_4, 
           Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) rn
      FROM YourTable
  ) T
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Account, Value_1, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) rn
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE Value_1 <> '') T1 ON T.Account = T1.Account AND T.rn = T1.rn
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Account, Value_2, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) rn
        FROM YourTable 
        WHERE Value_2 <> ''
  ) T2 ON T.Account = T2.Account AND T.rn = T2.rn
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Account, Value_3, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) rn 
        FROM YourTable 
        WHERE Value_3 <> ''
  ) T3 ON T.Account = T3.Account AND T.rn = T3.rn
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT Account, Value_4, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) rn 
        FROM YourTable 
        WHERE Value_4 <> ''
  ) T4 ON T.Account = T4.Account AND T.rn = T4.rn
WHERE T1.Value_1 IS NOT NULL 
  OR T2.VALUE_2 IS NOT NULL 
  OR T3.VALUE_3 IS NOT NULL 
  OR T4.VALUE_4 IS NOT NULL
```

If your values are stored as blanks, then this should work.  If they are stored as NULLs, replace <> '' with IS NOT NULL.

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1613/1).

Good luck.